# Is there a VM that can be used to run a function described by self modifying Bytecode?

Tags: ios, virtual-machine, bytecode, self-modifying

I want to be able to run self modifying code without actually marking the memory the code is in as executable. To do this my plan is to represent the code as bytecode then run the bytecode in an interpreter/vm.

My question is, is there a bytecode instruction set that corresponds closely to traditional HW (CPU/Stack/Heap), and allows the memory the bytecode is in to be modified (assuming I map it into the VM somehow).

**Nice to have:** Ability to target the bytecode instruction set from a C/C++ compiler, and for the Interpreter/VM to be "lightweight" in terms of CPU and memory overhead.

Comment: You could always write your own VM -- it's not that hard.

Comment: @HotLicks That may be where I go next, but I would prefer to use an established solution. Preferably one with existing support for generating the bytecode from languages like C using LLVM or another compile front end so users can reuse existing code.

Comment: Easiest, of course, would be to start with Java and *javac*.